# Migrating form twitter-bootstrap to zurb-foundation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been using Twitter bootstrap for my simple [blog](http://blog.sanjeevonline.com) from quite some time now and am looking forward to migrate to the bootstrap3. However, I have also been reading some very good stuff about Zurb Foundation and would like to try that first before moving over to bootstrap3.

I am a little noob when it comes to client side technologies so would appreciate some pointers on how to go about migrating from bootstrap to Foundation. Would it be a straight forward migration or a tricky one?

Would appreciate some unbiased opinion from experts in this area.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it would be a simple process. You would need to change the structor, classes and ids of your HTML.

For example if you wanted a dropdown menu you will have something like this.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you wanted to use Foundation you would need to change the HTML to something like this.

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1">Has Dropdown</a>
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
  <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
```

Obviously the CSS would be different but I imagine you expect that from migrating. 
One other thing I can think of is that foundation uses  Sass and not less like bootstrap so if you have written any less that will need to changed to  Sass.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be great if there was a migration guide.  I know it's not a completely mechanical process, but a set of mappings and strategies that work for other people could make this process a lot easier.  We're about to undertake a migration process, so maybe we'll have some notes to share.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with bootstrap.  It is harder to override the styling of bootstrap than foundation 4 - but the documentation is better.

As you can see from the previous answer - migration would be pretty painful.  If you wanted to use Foundation it would be easier to start over from scratch.  And Foundation 5 can be pretty painful to set up.

I strongly suggest you learn to use LESS with Bootstrap. (Or SASS/Compass for Foundation.)  Customization is much less painful than with the raw CSS.